# Use Green's Function to solve ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I have the following ODE to solve via Green's function:

$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - y = F(x)
$$

for $0<x<1$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=y(1)=0$.

So far I have done the following:

I try a Green's function $G(x,\xi)$ that satisfies

$$
\frac{d^2G}{dx^2} - G = \delta(x-\xi).
$$

For $x \neq \xi$, we have that $\delta(x-\xi)=0$ and so the ODE becomes

$$
\frac{d^2G}{dx^2} - G = 0.
$$

This has the solution:

$$
G(x,\xi) = A_1e^x - B_1e^{-x} \text{ for } x < \xi \text{ and } G(x,\xi) = A_2e^x - B_2e^{-x} \text{ for } x > \xi.
$$

Applying the boundary condition $G(0) = G(1) = 1$, we get that $B_1 = -A_1$ and $B_2 = -A_2e^2$. Thus the solution is now of the form

$$
G(x,\xi) = A_1(e^x - e^{-x}) \text{ for } x < \xi \text{ and } G(x,\xi) = A_2(e^x - e^{2-x}) \text{ for } x > \xi.
$$

We require $[G_x(x,\xi)]^{\xi_+}_{\xi} = 1$. This results in

$$
A_2(e^{\xi} + e^{2-\xi}) - A_1(e^{\xi}+e^{-\xi}) = 1.
$$

How can I finish this problem?
Thanks